# Ruby/Sqlite3: Please switch to passing bind parameters as an array

Tags: ruby, sqlite3-ruby

New to ruby here - getting an error about bind parameters in my `db_add_notice` method. Having trouble googling this error for some reason. Can someone point out what's wrong? Thanks.

./check.rb:57:in `db_add_notice' is calling SQLite3::Database#execute with nil or multiple bind params
without using an array.  Please switch to passing bind parameters as an array.
Support for bind parameters as *args will be removed in 2.0.0.

```
...
# add a usn entry to the datase
def db_add_notice(db, usn_number, href, title, description)
   db.execute("INSERT INTO usn_notice (usn_number, href, title, description) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", usn_number, href, title, description)
end
...
db_add_notice(db, usn_number, href, title, description)
...
```

Comment: Have you tried passing the variables in an array, that is, `db.execute("INSERT INTO usn_notice (usn_number, href, title, description) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", [usn_number, href, title, description])`?

Comment: Ah, that works. Thank you!